# Find out where a viewer comes from with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Does anyone know if it is possible to determine which company a visitor to your site comes from?  For example, if a person is sitting in the offices at Coca-cola or IBM or whatever and visits your site, can Google Analytics (or some other service akin to that) tell that you are coming from those locations?

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics *does* display a [Network](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1153379) for each hit - depending upon the size of the organization and its network architecture, you *may* be able to determine which organization's network a visitor is coming from.

Refer to Wikipedia's article on [Autonomous Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_System_%28Internet%29) and the IANA's [Number Resources](http://www.iana.org/numbers) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

No, analytics won't give you that.

You will need a service/product like this:

http://www.maxmind.com/en/organization